# High CPU usage in Chrome/Opera

Tags: google-chrome, performance, cpu, web-browser

When I open 1-2 tabs with sites that have many images (e-shop as an example) the CPU usage gets to 100% for Chrome/Opera/Firefox.

What I've tried:

1. Reset Chrome to default settings
2. Disabled all extensions
3. Disabled "Use hardware acceleration" in Chrome settings
4. Checked task manager in Chrome. Couldn't find anything except that a process called "Browser" takes all the CPU (100%+)
5. Run malware check on MacOS with 2 different programs (avast and malwarebyte)
6. Run diagnostics after restarting MacOS

Looks like any browser with webkit engine suddenly started consuming 100% CPU on any site which has at least some dynamic content, maybe images or some JS or something like that. Basically any site.

MacOS version: Big Sur 11.1

CPU: 2,5 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7

RAM: 16 GB

Graphics: Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

Comment: If you disable hardware acceleration, then it's going to do it in software. With the CPU. Chrome does have a bit of a reputation for CPU/RAM usage. Have you tried Safari, or Vivaldi on the same sites for comparison?

Comment: When I enabled hardware acceleration, I still have 100%+ CPU, but the difference (at first glance) than when it's disabled, then Google Chrome Renderer takes most of CPU, while when it's enabled then Google Chrome (not renderer) takes 100%+ CPU. Hmmm. I'm going to try Safari, I just don't want to switch it it because I got used to chrome dev tools...

Comment: Same for Safari, now I got 100% on mtlcompilerservice process

Comment: If you're getting this for 'any site', then thats very wrong indeed. What happens if you run it in a new user account (as a test)?

Comment: Same. It behaves this way: when I open a new site, for 30-60 seconds I got high CPU usage, fans are working hard :) Then after some time, everything calms down. Tested on new user on Safari. It feels like it tries to render everything which is hard for OS for some reason

Comment: Can you provide a sample link?

Comment: Chrome / Opera use the same engine underneath - Blink. And Chrome is known to be a CPU and memory hog because of the way it is designed. Safari uses the WebKit engine. And Firefox Gecko engine. Both these browsers use less resource. Please post a screenshot of your `Activity Monitor` (with CPU tab) with Chrome running. Also open `Console` and post a screenshot of it if it displays any errors or faults.

Comment: I've made a video with opened activity monitor, google and google task manager. https://www.loom.com/share/454c3ff1e2fd418ea8e3ed8c75c120b7 . So for 1 tab if I skim some links in amazon CPU gets spike up to 80%, then calms down. but it's enough to run the fans for a minute.. =\

Answer (score 3):

Setting two system preferences, `reduce transparency` and `reduce motion`, seem to have made a significant difference for me across several browsers:

> 1. Open the  Apple menu, open ‘System Preferences’, then select the “Accessibility” preference panel
> 2. Choose “Display” settings
> 3. Check the boxes for “Reduce motion” and “Reduce transparency”
> 4. Exit out of System Preferences

**Suggestion and steps from OSXDaily article; citation below.*

Casual observation using Activity Monitor suggests browsers now use something like 30% of the CPU and memory (very casual method: I left the same moderately large number of windows and tabs open in Safari as I made the changes. Before: many fan cycles, much heat, many spinning beachballs, high % of resources in Activity Monitor. After: dramatic absence of all these telltales.

My guess at the reason: I noted a significant change in the appearance of the top bars of each window; browsers with lots of windows open may require a lot of resources just to calculate how all of them should appear with partial transparency.

I ran across this suggestion in a Jan 20, 2021 **OSXDaily** article *[macOS Big Sur Slow or Laggy? 8 Tips to Help Speed Up the Mac Again](https://osxdaily.com/2021/01/20/macos-big-sur-slow-speed-tips-fix/)* - credit to them for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same issue. It's not very good even in Safari. I suspect the mtlcompilerservice, as I load pages I see a lot of instances of it in the Activity Monitor, consuming high CPU. TGPro shows high temperature of the CPU, 90+ celcius. Video playback heats up the device but loading pages and browsing around is the worst offender.

I have the 15" mid 2014 model with Iris Pro & Nvidia gt 750m. I thought the reason for overheating/fans-kicking-in-whenever-they-please was that Apple changed some things as to how GPUs work in Big Sur.

I'll try installing Big Sur to a separate volume, and if that doesn't help, I'll re-install macOS, starting from High Sierra and update here.

--

Idle temp: 54-60 C 
 Browsing: 70+ C

Comment: Tell me how it goes please, I gave up since I got no idea what to do. Tried everything I could. People usually say that chrome is CPU greedy, but come on, not for one site with few images. Definitely something with OS.